# CSS formatting context for columns

Tags: css

This is my first post here and I'm French, I beg your pardon for the language ...

I created a system columns in css, combining the display rule: `table-cell` and percentages with `.columns` class.

I would like a `.columns` child element may be equivalent in width to two or more default items if necessary. So I created classes (`.C2`, `.C3`, `.C4` ...) to be affixed to the relevant child elements (`.C2` class for 2 off items, etc).

This solution works very well in a form (exactly in the form element) but I can not reproduce this behaviour within a single div. So I tried to get all the features of the form element css to affix them to the div... without result.

Here is an example :

```css
@import url(http://scriptura.github.io/Styles/Public/Main.css);
```

```html
<html>
  <body itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage" class="onepage-color">
    <section class="section">
      <div class="wrap grid12">
        <h2 class="highlight">Test Columns</h2>
        <div class="columns">
          <div>
            <h2 class="h5 highlight">Test n°1</h2>
            <p><code>form .columns</code></p>
            <form>
              <div class="columns-smallspace">
                <div class="input">
                  <input type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                  <input type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                  <input type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                  <input type="text"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="columns-smallspace">
                <div class="input c2">
                  <input type="text" value=".c2"/>
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                  <input type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                  <input type="text"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="columns-smallspace">
                <div class="input c3">
                  <input type="text" value=".c3"/>
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                  <input type="text"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            <p class="message-success">Ici, on voit que la colonne comportant l'input .c2, prend bien la place de deux colonnes quand elle est placée dans un <code>form</code>. Idem pour .c3 qui prend la place de trois colonnes.</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2 class="h5 highlight">Test n°2</h2>
            <p><code>div .columns</code></p>
            <div style="display:table;" class="elleEstIci">
              <div class="columns-smallspace">
                <div class="input">
                  <input type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                  <input type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                  <input type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                  <input type="text"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="columns-smallspace">
                <div class="input c2">
                  <input type="text" value=".c2"/>
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                  <input type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                  <input type="text"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="columns-smallspace">
                <div class="input c3">
                  <input type="text" value=".c3"/>
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                  <input type="text"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p class="message-error">La même classe .c2 placée dans le même contexte, à l'exception notable d'une <code>div</code> à la place du <code>form</code>, donne lieu à une anarchie totale sur la deuxième ligne (idem pour .c3)...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="h5 highlight">Quid ?</h2>
        <p class="message">Comment configurer la div parente du deuxième test (div.elleEstIci) de manière à arriver au même résultat que le premier exemple&nbsp;?<br/>J'ai l'impression d'avoir tout essayé (display:table, etc)...</p>
        <p class="message-info">Vous trouverez la feuille de style complète à cette addresse (cf. lignes 437+) : <a href="https://github.com/Scriptura/Scriptura/blob/master/Web/Styles/Development/_core.scss">Scriptura sur Github</a>.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you have a solution, and I'm interested, in advance, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I found: it was necessary to declare a `width: 100%` on `[class ^ = "columns"]> *`.

So the child elements, and not the parent element as I thought at first. Sounds simple ... but afterwards I have brainstormed.

Subject resolved.